# prevent resharper from automatically fixing issues

Tags: resharper

I noticed that Resharper automatically applies fixes (e.g. removing unnecessary namespace prefixes) in methods that I am **not** working on within the file I'm working on.  How do I turn this off? (I only want to fix things if I take specific action).

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question, I'm not sure whether it is about disabling automatic fixes, or just make them more local.

1. What you're talking about, is called [Code Cleanup](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html). You can disable parts of that in the ReSharper options, including the "Optimize Using directives", which you were talking about.
2. If you just want to cleanup/format a part of a file, you have the option to first select the method/code part, and *then* hit the shortcut to cleanup. Then, all modifications will just apply to the selected area, not the file.